# How to make valid/invalid checks in csv on PHP

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

How can I check data from csv such as

```
 17,William,10/3/1997,WilliamKDollinger@trashymail.com,MN,55401
```

and check for example they can not be older than 21. Then make 2 files..valid and invalid, where if they are over 21 they go in valid csv file and invalid ones go in invalid csv. Thanks.

My current php code is this:

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile = 'C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\orders.csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Umm, are you asking what an `if` is?

Comment: no i know the logic, just need a starting point like how to scan each line or that column...

Comment: You would have to take care of that from your initial form input, and use `if { // in this age bracket // do something }` type of thing. Least that's what I would do from the "get go" and not having to worry about it "later". It would be a heckuva lot simpler that way.

Comment: `fgetcsv` returns an array, so all you need to do is check the first value and then `fputcsv` the line to the corresponding files

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos_of_col = 0 // column to check
if($line_of_text[$pos_of_col] > 21){ //add $line_of_text to valid csv }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the lines, and then use `explode()` to separate the line by a delimiter (comma, in this case), and store the values in variables.

```
$str = '17,William,10/3/1997,WilliamKDollinger@trashymail.com,MN,55401';
$str = explode(',', $str);

$age = $str[0];
$name = $str[1];
$dob = $str[2];
$email = $str[3];
...
```

Once that's done, you can simply use if statements with your logic to compare them and do whatever you want with it.

For example:

```
if( $age > 21 ) {

//hurray, you're older than 21

}
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/pS6CdVrW

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, could you please elaborate from whats the first thing i would need to do from the end of my current code?